# Cannot move io::Error out of Peekable Result

Tags: error-handling, rust, iterator, borrow-checker, ownership

I'm just trying to propagate the IO error:

```
enum MyError {
    EOF,
    IO(std::io::Error),
}

fn peek_byte<R>(mut p: Peekable<Bytes<R>>) -> Result<u8, MyError>
where
    R: Read,
{
    match p.peek() {
        None => Err(MyError::EOF),
        Some(Err(e)) => Err(MyError::IO(*e)),  // <==== error is here
        Some(Ok(byte)) => Ok(*byte),
    }
}
```

But, I get the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*e` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:17:41
   |
17 |         Some(Err(e)) => Err(MyError::IO(*e)),
   |                                         ^^ move occurs because `*e` has type `std::io::Error`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I actually understand all of this. I know why I'm getting the error, and what the error means. What I don't know is how to accomplish my task and propagate the IO error into my error type.

I have tried `e`, `*e`, `e.clone()`, `*e.clone()`, `*(e.clone())`, but they all either produce a "type mismatch" or a "cannot move" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Peekable` iterator holds ownership of the next value of its internal iterator and returns references via `peek`, but if you actually want the owned value you just call `next` as usual (which does advance the iterator but I think that's okay in this case since you're not actually consuming any content from the iterator but just trying to return an error):

```rust
use std::io;
use std::io::Bytes;
use std::io::Read;
use std::iter::Peekable;

enum MyError {
    EOF,
    IO(io::Error),
}

fn peek_byte<R>(mut p: Peekable<Bytes<R>>) -> Result<u8, MyError>
where
    R: Read,
{
    match p.peek() {
        None => Err(MyError::EOF),
        Some(Err(e)) => Err(MyError::IO(p.next().unwrap().unwrap_err())),
        Some(Ok(byte)) => Ok(*byte),
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=30bb9064b927f109470827b8aa78ad2b)

Comment: I had thought of that, but I was unsure of the guarantee that next() would always return the same value as peek(). (What if the error condition goes away?)

Seems like a good solution for my problem, though. Thank you!

Comment: `next()` always returns the same value as `peek()` because `Peekable` saves the value. Errors in Rust are just plain data like anything else, even if the underlying situation which caused the error goes away `Peekable` will still be holding on to the original Error instance.